# ScrollView in PanResponder component

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to create a card deck in the Bumble style (you have a card that you can swipe horizontally and can also scroll vertically to see more photos/info)

My problem is that whilst on iOS this works perfectly fine, in Android the ScrollView inside the PanResponder component seems to take priority on the gesture handling.

I have tried to dynamically change the scrollEnabled on the ScrollView as soon as a horizontal gesture appears, but this did not help.

Any chance you have any solutions?

Comment: That's the limitation of Android ScrollView, you can not solve it via panresponder, gestuer and any other.

Comment: I have write an component to solve this, but per StackOverflow 's policy, I am not sure wether allowed or not to list here.